# PowerShell txt file comparison not finding matches

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell adventures continue… After finally figuring out file manipulation and some regular expressions to format my text, I finally have 2 text files which I need to compare.

```
Compare-Object $(Get-Content C:\File1.txt) $(Get-Content C:\File2.txt) -includeequal > C:\Results.txt
```

Problem:
When using Compare-Object and Get-Content on 2 separate text files the comparison results show no matches. I know for a fact this is incorrect as I can manually find strings identical to both. The text is a random ID number structured like so:

**GTD-LVOE-FS-0032**

Each text file itself may contain multiple copies for a particular ID number and File2 is a master list containing all occurrences of the ID numbers.

Solution:
I expect Compare-Object with the –includeequal to return some == results as I know this is the case. Are there formatting issues I may be overlooking that are causing this or does Compare-Object not work like I am expecting when multiple identical strings exist within and between files?

**EDIT:**

As a test I created 2 text files each containing the following.

```
GTD-LVOE-43-0021
GTD-LVOE-43-0021
GTD-LVOE-43-0021
GTD-LVOE-43-0021
```

I expect Compare-Object to say these text files are identical, rather it returns that File2 contains the strings. It seems to me the issue is with Compare-Object handling identical strings within one of the variables created for the compare. Is there another CMDLET or method to use for comparing objects when there are multiple identical strings within the variables that need to be compared?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the files.

Comment: I edited the post to show the contents of my test file. File1 and File2 have those 4 identical lines. The lines are identical within each document and between each file. I was expecting PowerShell to output four == for the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me (based on the content you posted, same content for file1 and file2):

```
PS> compare (gc File1.txt) (gc File2.txt) -IncludeEqual | ft -a

InputObject      SideIndicator
-----------      -------------
GTD-LVOE-43-0021 ==
GTD-LVOE-43-0021 ==
GTD-LVOE-43-0021 ==
GTD-LVOE-43-0021 ==
```

Comment: OK, it does work using your script. Do you mind looking at the script I posted in my original post and telling me why my approach was wrong? I am not sure I understand the difference between Compare and Compare-Object.

Comment: compare is just an alias for Compare-Object, it should work the same using both.

Comment: odd... I will just assume PICNIC somewhere in my previous attempts.

Comment: AH! update, I am experiencing this problem with PowerShell v1.0 on xp, but as you stated, this is working fine with PowerShell on Win 7.

Comment: As far as I remember you'd have to adjust the -SyncWindow parameter to half the length of the longest file or something like that. The default value was 5 IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll just avoid XP, which is prolly for the best anyway and just try to do this stuff on a win7 machine with the latest PowerShell.